# in sql server what is the difference between user_type_id and system_type_id in sys.types

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes

What is the difference between user_type_id and system_type_id in the view of sys.types in sql server?

I want to inner join sys.columns with sys.types to get the data types of columns in a user table, but these two views both have two fields user_type_id and system_type_id, which one should be used?

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188021.aspx)?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You almost never want to join `sys.columns.system_type_id = sys.types.system_type_id`. This will lead to [duplicate records](http://jessesql.blogspot.co.at/2009/05/querying-syscolumns-systypes.html) in the case of user-defined types.

There are two JOINs which *do* make sense. Both of them work equivalently for built-in types.

1. **sys.columns.user_type_id = sys.types.user_type_id**

   For a built-in type, it returns the built-in type.

   For a user-defined type, it returns the user-defined type.
2. **sys.columns.system_type_id = sys.types.user_type_id**

   For a built-in type, it returns the built-in type.

   For a user-defined type, it returns *the built-in base type*. This might make sense, for example, if you want to get all *varchar* columns, *including* all user-defined columns based on varchar.

Answer (score 11):

From Heinzi's answer (May 5, 2014):

> sys.columns.system_type_id = sys.types.user_type_id
>
> For a built-in type, it returns the built-in type.
>
> For a user-defined type, it returns the built-in base type. This might make >sense, for example, if you want to get all varchar columns, including all >user-defined columns based on varchar.

I would add that this (second) solution will not be a complete solution if you are looking to list all columns and their data types.

Since SQL Server 2008, spatial and hierarchical data have been introduced as (apparently) built-in user-defined data types. These have never been linked to any base type. This means that although they have a system_type_id (namely, 240), this id does not correspond to any user_type_id.

In other words, an attempt to join a system_type_id column with a user_type_id column will remove all records with spatial or hierarchical data types from the query results.

If you are only interested in the built-in base types, but want to see results for columns containing spatial and hierarchical data as well, you may want to use the following modified join:

```
select t.name, ...
from sys.columns c join sys.types t
on c.system_type_id = t.user_type_id
   or (c.system_type_id = 240 and c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id)
```

This will generate results for all columns, including those with hierarchical and spatial data.