# TSQL - Why sysname is created when I create nVarChar column?

Tags: t-sql, nvarchar

I have a table in my tsql datatable:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test
(
     Col nVarChar (50) null
)
GO
```

And then I executed query:

```
Select 
    c.name As Name, ty.name as Type, c.max_length As MaxLenght, c.precision As Precision, c.scale As Scale, c.is_nullable As IsNullable, *
From
    sys.schemas s
    inner join sys.tables t on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    inner join sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
    inner join sys.types ty on ty.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
Where
    s.name LIKE 'dbo' AND t.name LIKE 'Test'
```

The question is... Why there are [Two Rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SV6JY.png)?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY system_type_id ORDER BY system_type_id)
      , *
FROM sys.types;
```

Check the first column for values >1...

There are few types mapping to the same `system_type_id`. Some names are just an *alias* for something else...

### UPDATE

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20348522/5089204) addresses the same issue...